# Sharepoint 2016 and infopath 2010

Tags: infopath, 2016

We currently run SharePoint 2010 Enterprise and use InfoPath forms (InfoPath designer 2010). We have recently upgraded to Office 2016 but still have the same InfoPath designer 2010. If we upgrade to SharePoint 2016 will the existing forms still work and will we be able to use InfoPath designer 2010 to modify and create new forms?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you are doing in the forms. You have to review each and every form to determine if the upgrade will work in a test environment. I have successfully upgraded many farms and written PowerShell scripts to crawl my farms looking for InfoPath forms in Form Libraries as well as List Edit and New item forms. We use the resulting list of forms to first, check to see if they are still in use, then later, for testing. Probably the biggest issue is when you migrate from Classic to Claims Authentication. This may break your InfoPath forms if your are getting the current user and then passing it outside the form.

You will need InfoPath 2013 to update any forms that you bring to SharePoint 2013/2016.

[I just answered a similar question here.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/215923/how-to-migrate-sharepoint-2010-to-sharepoint-2016-on-premise/215943#215943)