# InfoPath forms in SharePoint 2016

Tags: infopath, designer-workflow, 2016

We are currently migrating from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2016. We have more than 200 InfoPath forms in our environment in current (SharePoint 2010) version. Are these can be migrated and used as is? Will SP2016 have the same ability as of SP2010? We also have some InfoPath forms associated to workflows. Can these be working as it is in this new environment?
What kind of changes and how big am I looking here? Can any one throw some insights and suggestions. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to migrate first to SharePoint 2013 and upgrade the site, and then perform another migration to 2016

also refer below links
[Sharepoint 2016 and infopath 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/210799/sharepoint-2016-and-infopath-2010)

https://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2013/03/infopath-and-sharepoint-2013-upgrading-your-forms/